# SharePoint Online - Get items from folder threshold issue

Tags: sharepoint-online, list-view, list-view-threshold

I have a SP List with multiple sub-folders. 
Each item in sub-folder has status column as Not Started/Ready
Total Items in list with Status Not Started -20
Total items in list with Status Ready -7000

I am trying to get items from a particular folder against Status Ready. 
Items in folder with status ready - 7. 
Items in folder with status ready - 2. 
Status column is indexed. 
However, i am still getting threshold issue.

```
   "<View Scope='RecursiveAll'> " +
                        "<Query>" +
                        "<Where>" +
                                    "<And><Eq>" +
                                        "<FieldRef Name='FileDirRef' />" +
                                        "<Value Type='Text'>"+ $logItem['Title'] +"</Value>" +
                                        "</Eq><Eq><FieldRef Name='Status'/>" +
                    "<Value Type='Text'>Ready</Value></Eq></And>" +
                        "</Where>" +
                        "<OrderBy Override='TRUE'><FieldRef Name='FileDirRef' /></OrderBy>" +
                        "</Query>" +
                        "<ViewFields><FieldRef Name='Modified' /><FieldRef Name='Editor' /></ViewFields>" +
                        "<RowLimit Paged='TRUE'>5000</RowLimit>" +
                        "</View>";
```

If i fire the same query against status Not Started, it works as expected. Does it account for all items in list irrespective of folder path. Please suggest